# LaTeX Embedded PDFs not showing or printing

Tags: pdf, svg, latex, adobe

I have a set of SVGs that have been converted into PDFs using inkscape. 
These are then compiled with latex and attempted to be viewed in a reader.

Pdflatex completes successfully and is error free, yet when I print form either Preview or Adobe Reader, the result is identical to the left pane in the screen grab enclosed.

Adobe Reader also only sees the pdf in this way.

I am able to print the original pdfs, so the error must lie in latex or the viewers.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One working solution lies in converting SVG's  to eps:

```
  inkscape -z --export-area-drawing <input filename+ path>.svg -E   <output filename + path>.eps --export-ps-level=3
```

... and then letting pdf latex convert them into a pdf during compiling to embed them in the original document.

```
 \includegraphics[...]{filename.eps}
```